# Are these table views?

Tags: ios, tableview

I would like to display some data relative to an object (for example the object would be a Recipe or a Contact person ) that would be editable.

I would like to display the object data like this (see pictures below) but I'm wondering whether I should use a Table View.
Are the details views below using using Table View to display their data ?

[image: contact detail] [image: recipe detail]

Thanks for helping me figuring it out !

Comment: Simple answer **YES** they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing are *grouped* `UITableViews`. That sections them out, as you are seeing above. Generally, this setting is selected under the attributes inspector in IB under style.

**Objective-C:**

```
UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

**Swift:**

```
let tv:UITableView = UITableView(frame: frame, style: .Grouped)
```

**Interface Builder**:

[image]

**More info**:

The inherent challenge with these types of table views is that the data does not have a solid relationship. For example, in a normal table view all of the cells are usually driven off of one datasource (i.e. like a Post model or something similar). With these, it's something like "Rate App" or "Visit Us Online", which are not similar.

For this reason, when setting up this kind of table view I would recommend taking a look at this github, which makes it less painful: https://github.com/romaonthego/RETableViewManager

Comment: I don't disagree with it being a `UITableView` with style grouped this correctly answers the question so I will not do a -1 However I do disagree with the second paragraph about it being challenging. I totally think this is incorrect. Yes it is usually driven of one datasource but why are you saying that a grouped version doesn't have a solid relationship with the data, that statement is wrong

Comment: I did not say to take it as Gospel, but from my experience and talking with several other developers that has been the case. Look at github and you'll see several repos talking about and addressing the problem. Heck, there is even mention of it in a WWDC talk. My example refers to the "Settings" type table view, which usually contains things that don't relate well. Rate my app and visit us online generally don't fit into one model nicely. So to say "that statement is wrong"...is wrong. The approach will always be different, sometimes what I said is true, sometimes what you said is true.

Comment: I'd say its more opinion based that part of your answer and doesn't relate to the question being asked to which point makes it wrong. The reason I say its opinion based is because you find it a challenge I don't I've never had an issue with them. Yes I will admit they could be better but never had an issue.

Comment: And I will agree with you that my opinion doesn't necessarily answer the question, that's true. I just added it for kicks and felt it somewhat relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is **YES** they are `UITableView`s. They are `UITableView`s with a `UITableViewStyle` `UITableViewStyleGrouped` or for swift it's just `Grouped`.

You can easily create an instance of one of these by doing:

**Objective-C**

```
UITableView *groupedTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame
                                                             style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```